# How do i run a mysql app without mysql connector installed?

Tags: c#, mysql

I made an C# application on visual studio, and this application connects to a MySQL Server, it works nice on my computer since I installed the full developer version of it.

But it doesn't run on other machines unless I install MySql connector, if I don't, it will stop working and not launch.

Is there anyway to run it without having mysql connector installed? Or add mysql connector installation to my app?

Comment: What is the error it gives you? Do you have "Copy Local" set to true on the reference DLL? You should use the NuGet package instead of the installer, it is a lot easier to use.

Comment: it was giving me that error: system.io.filenotfoundexception

Comment: Can you tell me more about this NuGet?

Comment: http://www.nuget.org/ and http://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bundle the MySql Connector/Net with your program. Connector/Net is available as an msi file that a Visual Studio Installer project in the same solution as your program's project can include alongside your program's installer as a dependency.

The Connector is licensed under the GPL, so make sure you understand your obligations if you choose to distribute it in this manner.

Comment: how do i do that? i mean how do i put the connector installer on my application installer?

Comment: Ok i get it i just had to publish my application in order to get the DLL included.